# CsvHelper with IBrowserFile

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I want to use an IBrowserFile with csvHelper.
But what do I need to enter in my StreamReader parameters ?

In the StreamReader you are supposed to enter a *path*. I use a IBrowserFile so what do I enter for "path"

I tried that code :

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file.Name)))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear,

Comment: `In the StreamReader you are supposed to enter a path.` no, you're supposed to enter a *stream*, that's why it's called StreamReader. The overload that accepts a path is a convenience method that opens a file stream. IBrowserFile has an `OpenReadStream` method

Comment: Ok, now I get that error : 'Argument 1 : cannot convert from System.IO.Stream to System.IO.TextReader'.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `IBrowserFile.OpenReadStream()` to your `StreamReader`.

```cs
public IList<Foo> ReadFile(IBrowserFile file)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        return csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: it throws "Synchronous reads are not supported." exception

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        
    }
 }
```

Helped from [Blazor Serverで作る資産管理アプリ](https://qiita.com/_gobo/items/f8700ed7b9f51e9b9fb5)